# Java BigDecimal operations "arbitrarily" showing incorrect number of decimal places

Tags: java, formatting, decimal, bigdecimal

I'm trying to solve an exercise using the BigDecimal class, but for some values it doesn't respect the correct number of decimal places to show.
For the values 5.0 to 12.5 it shows extra decimal places. Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

This is an adapted version of the code:

```
MathContext mc = new MathContext(2, RoundingMode.UP);

BigDecimal min = new BigDecimal("2.00");
BigDecimal adt = new BigDecimal("0.50");
BigDecimal lim = new BigDecimal("3.00");

for (float f = 5f; f <= 30f ; f += 0.5f) {
    String s = Float.toString(f);
    BigDecimal hours = new BigDecimal(s);
    BigDecimal charge = min.add(hours.subtract(lim).round(mc).multiply(adt));
    System.out.println(f + " = " + charge);
}
```

Output:

```
5.0 = 3.000
5.5 = 3.250
6.0 = 3.500
6.5 = 3.750
7.0 = 4.000
7.5 = 4.250
8.0 = 4.500
8.5 = 4.750
9.0 = 5.000
9.5 = 5.250
10.0 = 5.500
10.5 = 5.750
11.0 = 6.000
11.5 = 6.250
12.0 = 6.500
12.5 = 6.750
13.0 = 7.00
13.5 = 7.50
14.0 = 7.50
14.5 = 8.00
15.0 = 8.00
15.5 = 8.50
16.0 = 8.50
16.5 = 9.00
17.0 = 9.00
17.5 = 9.50
18.0 = 9.50
18.5 = 10.00
19.0 = 10.00
19.5 = 10.50
20.0 = 10.50
20.5 = 11.00
21.0 = 11.00
21.5 = 11.50
22.0 = 11.50
22.5 = 12.00
23.0 = 12.00
23.5 = 12.50
24.0 = 12.50
24.5 = 13.00
25.0 = 13.00
25.5 = 13.50
26.0 = 13.50
26.5 = 14.00
27.0 = 14.00
27.5 = 14.50
28.0 = 14.50
28.5 = 15.00
29.0 = 15.00
29.5 = 15.50
30.0 = 15.50
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever use a floating point type as the index of a for loop.

Comment: You can round using a MathContext object, but only for display.

Comment: @DavidConrad: Although in this case it works, both because of `<=` and because all the values can be represented exactly.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Yes, but getting in the habit of looping over floats is setting yourself up for future heartache, as I'm sure you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably a misunderstanding of `MathContext`. With `MathContext(2, RoundingMode.UP)` you're not saying "*I want 2 decimal places*", but you say "*I want to reduce the precision of my number to 2 digits*".

If you have a look at your numbers, the scale (number of decimal places) is 2 where `hours - lim >= 10`

If you have a detailed look at the two examples `hours=12.5` and `hours=13.0`

```
//hours = 12.5:
var subtract = hours.subtract("3.00"); // 12.5 - 3.00 = 9.50 (subtract.scale = 2)
var round = subtract.round(mc); // 9.5 (round.scale = 1)
var result = round.multiply("0.50") // 9.5 * 0.50 = 4.750 (result.scale = round.scale + subtract.scale = 3)
```

```
//hours = 13.0:
var subtract = hours.subtract("3.00"); // 13.0 - 3.00 = 10.00 (subtract.scale = 2)
var round = subtract.round(mc); // 10 (round.scale = 0)
var result = round.multiply("0.50") // 10 * 0.50 = 5.00 (result.scale = round.scale + subtract.scale = 2)
```

You see the scale of the rounded decimal becomes 0 as soon as it's value becomes >= 10. The scale of the result of multiply is always the sum of the scale of the two multiplicants.

To set the scale of a `BigDecimal` use `BigDecimal.setScale(int, RoundingMode)` instead of `MathContext`.

Comment: Tried with .setScale, worked nice, thanks. This whole scale thing is pretty confusing